# Слияние по общему слову наложением

Tags: python, алгоритм

У меня есть список из 3 элементов, каждый типа tuple.

```py
[
    ('Ann', 'Helen', 'Daria'), 
    ('Marie', 'Daria', 'Kristoffer'), 
    ('Barbara', 'Ann', 'Kristoffer'),
]
```

Последовательность такова, что каждый последующий внутри tuple "младше" прeдидущего, что-то вроде как *предок > родитель > дитя*.

Я хочу сделать слияние трех в одно:

```
 |            |'Ann'(0)|'Helen'(1)|          |'Daria'(2)| 
 |            |        |          |'Marie'(0)|'Daria'(1)|'Kristoffer'(2)
 |'Barbara'(0)|'Ann'(1)|          |          |          |'Kristoffer'(2)
```

В скобках индекс элемента, который поможет решить, что сделать append либо prepend.

То есть конечный результат **`Barbara > Ann > Helen > Marie > Daria > Kristoffer`**

Comment: А почему, например, Helen идёт раньше, чем Marie? Почему Maria вообще не самая первая, хотя ни в одной из троек нет никого старше неё? Из ваших данных можно получить разные варианты решения, каждый из которых будет правильным.

Comment: Я знаю, что  Barbara идет перед Ann, эти значения, которые уже есть - уже сформатированные, на основе предидущих, что у меня есть. Если Вы хотите - я могу скинуть изначальную последовательность введенных значений, значения такие:

Comment: `Ann, Helen, Daria, 
Marie, Daria, Kristoffer,
Barbara, Ann, Kristoffer,
Helen, Marie`
Если заменить запутую на знак больше, вы получите последовательн того, кто старше кого.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. У вас в вашей "последовательности" имена повторяются. Объясните нормально суть задачи.

Comment: Я ввожу имена, который идут в последовательности по 3: предоок>родитель>дитя. В последем случае Helen, Marie, я знаю, что Helen > Marie, это мне помагает узнать, что будет перед Daria, а что после Ann.  Задача: скажите, кто старше кого, зная что, и tuple значений. Если прям дословно, то так: ( Ann > Helen >Daria) , (Marie> Daria> Kristoffer), (Barbara > Ann >Kristoffer) , (Helen> Marie). В случае с Barbara, я понимю, что она старше Ann и первая попадает в начало списка(так как в 3 tuple она идет перед Ann), Kristoffer самый младший. Надеюсь, это понятное и емкое объяснение задачи

Comment: Звучит как задача на использование бинарного дерева поиска. Почитайте об этой разновидности графа. Думаю это то, что может тебя выручить